# Why am i unable to debug an Provider Hosted SharePoint app?

Tags: sharepoint-addin, asp.net, provider-hosted-app, codebehind

I have a method which checks valid session which gets triggered in page load,I have placed break points in it for debugging purpose.When I run my provider hosted sharepoint app it does not hit the method.

The debug break-point shows

> The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document

Before posting this question,I referred many posts where some solutions where given including,
1.Enable `<compilation debug="true" />` in web.config file.

2.Do Enable just my code in VS.
and few others.

What can be done to enable debugging the method?

Comment: Are you trying to debug C# or JavaScript? Are you in IE or Chrome? You cannot debug JavaScript in Visual Studio if you are not using IE.

Comment: c# code and Used IE.The issue is resolved.Thanks for your response anyway.

Answer (score 7):

Right click on your solution -> Select `Set Startup Projects` -> Choose `Multiple Startup Projects` -> and select `Start` action for both app and app web projects. Also, app web project should be the first one.

This should do the trick.

Comment: Yeah it did! Thnks a lot

Comment: great. Please mark it as answer.

Comment: Unfortunately @kaarthickraman hasn't been seen since november 2016, but hopefully he will come back to accept the answer. +1